# append vs after jquery (page break issue)

Tags: jquery, css, page-break

```
$(this).after("<tr class='pagebreak'></tr>");
```

I am adding a tr like above, but, the page break is not working.

When I do:

```
$("#searchresult").append("<tr class='pagebreak'></tr>");
```

the page break is working.

Unfortunately I can't use `append` all the time because there are dynamic `tr` to add.

My css is below.

```
tr {display: table-row !important; } 
tr.pagebreak { display: block !important; page-break-after: always; }
```

***UPDATE:***

```
<table>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='dynamicsubtotal'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='dynamicsubtotal'></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: when do u need to insert a page break?

Comment: in my table i am adding records and i paginate them 10 at a time sometimes there is tr that i add which has subtotal that is the time i use after. i put the page break after the subtotal tr. when there is no sub total tr i just use append and it works fine. @root

Comment: It would help if u could provide an expected output and ur current html.

Comment: @root in general that would be how my table looks like and i need to add page break every other 10 value..sometimes i add 1 or 2 more tr after subtotal..that is when i use after..if no subtotal i use append and the pagebreak works ok.. Now i am assuming that the page break dont work if u use after. I am not sure if that is really the case

Comment: Please append the JS to your question :)

Comment: why not use nth-child in css to add the pagebreak? No need to add additional elements....

Comment: You aren't showing us where you get `#searchresult` or what `this` refers to.

Comment: @Sarcoma this refers to subtotal each subtotal i append the pagebreak so that the table is still intact because i paginate the table

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do it.

```
var count = 0;
$('table tr').each(function() {
     if($(this).hasClass('dynamicsubtotal') || count == 9) 
     {
         $('this').after('<tr class="page-break"><\tr>') 
     } else {
         count++;
     }
}
```

It's not tested though

Comment: OP needs to add new `tr` instead of just adding class to existing element

Comment: But only if the previous tr is not a dynamic subtotal? Do you want the break before or after the total? Not really seeing the problem.

Comment: In my table i am adding records and i paginate them 10 at a time sometimes there is tr that i add which has subtotal that is the time i use after. i put the page break after the subtotal tr. when there is no sub total tr i just use append and it works fine

Comment: Please update your question to reflect this. I think you need to rephrase the question to make it clearer what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: mate i can page break question is why it is not working when using `.after()` and working when using `.append()`

Comment: Because they do different things. `.after` places it after the selected element, `.append` places it at the end inside the selected element.

Comment: #searchresult is still throwing me, you say that it works when you append to it but it's not in the example you have provided

Comment: Can you double check that $(this) refers to the tag you think it does? If it is putting after the element that you expect it to then I can't see the problem it should work as you intend.

Comment: @Sarcoma it is adding correctly everything looks ok only problem is the part of the table that is suppose to be on next page is not on next page it is still with in the same page.. I am assuming that the page break is not working i tried adding style='dislay:block' to tr while adding to table same result. Im out of idea now

Answer (score 0):

Via css instead of adding elements?

```
tr:nth-child(10n+0) {
    display: block !important; page-break-after: always;
}
```

Comment: In my table i am adding records and i paginate them 10 at a time sometimes there is tr that i add which has subtotal that is the time i use after. i put the page break after the subtotal tr. when there is no sub total tr i just use append and it works fine